# Clickable textview (phone call intent)

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have this fragment, which shows a two columns list (implemented with an adapter). It represents a list of phone numbers, so the second column is just a list of numbers: I want to make each of these numbers clickable and, on click, the phone call must start. This is my code:

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    public static final String column1 = "column1";
    public static final String column2 = "column2";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    ListView lview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    populateList();
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final TextView tv = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.column2);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { **//this is the line getting NPE**
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String phone_no=tv.getText().toString().trim();
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}



private void populateList() {

    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> temp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp1.put(column1,"Home");
    temp1.put(column2, "55501982");
    list.add(temp1);

}
}
```

fragment_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    public static final String colonna1 = "column1";
    public static final String colonna2 = "column2";

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    Activity activity;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtFirst;
        TextView txtSecond;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column1);
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(column1));
        holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(column2));


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

rows.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/color_number"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I took two attempts: first, I added this code in MyFragment.java:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.column2);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phone_no=tv.getText().toString().trim();
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

But I'm getting NullPointerException:

```
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at com.example.myproject.fragments.MyFragment.onActivityCreated(MyFragment.java:44)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-26 16:58:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Then, I tried to add this line:

> android:autoLink="phone"

to rows.xml, but nothing happens on click. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you used the click listener, what was on the line which caused the NPE? (It says 38 in the log).

Comment: Sorry, it was tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

A ListView can have multiple items, therefore multiple TextView's to which you need to assign listeners. But how would you find the view inside the activity if there are multiple of them with the same id? :-) That's why you need to set the listener inside of your adapter, when inflating the custom item layout. Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        // Set the listener
        holder.txtSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                String phone_no=tv.getText().toString().trim();
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(column1));
    holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(column2));


    return convertView;
}
```

Note that we are setting the listener only when the view is inflating. Later it just get's re-used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried like you said: `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final TextView tv = (TextView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.column2);
  tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    String phone_no=tv.getText().toString().trim();
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
    startActivity(intent);

   }
  });
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

 }`

Still getting NPE.

Comment: @user3673449 Please, update the code on your question, also add the log and mark the line where you're getting the NPE.